# change background color of all view controllers if all classes are called (swift4)

Tags: core-data, global-variables, swift4, background-color, userdefaults

When the user visits all three view controllers in no particular order. I want all of the view controllers in this program to turn green. But only if all three classes are visited.  I don't know if this is a coredata or userdefulat thing.

```
import UIKit

class oneV: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
}

class twoV: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}

class threeV: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Comment: you want to flip the color right away ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UserDefaults Will be great for this, saving a flag for each `UIViewController` in its `viewDidLoad` function.

Then adding up those three flags into one, and check it in `viewWillAppear` in each `UIViewController`.

Check this Code Below.

```
// First create this extension to check on each value
public extension UIViewController {
    func isAllVistied() -> Bool {
        let a =  UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "VC1") // Key used to save inside the viewController
        let b =  UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "VC2")
        let c =  UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "VC3")
        if a && b && c {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage:** In each `UIViewController` use this code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "VC1") //Key changes based on the current viewController used in example (VC1, VC2, VC3)
    }
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if self.isAllVistied() {
            view.backgroundColor = .green
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works well. I would like to know how the first time all of the classes are triggered it goes to green but anything equal to or greater than 2 it goes to red. So for the first hit green then once they are all called again red? Thanks again for your help?